# Serialize C++ unordered_map to buffer (char*)

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, buffer, unordered-map

How can I serialize unordered_map to a buffer (char*)? I have searched around, most people recommend using boost serialization but they all use text_oarchive/text_iarchieve to serialize to a file or stringstream. I don't really understand text_oarchive (and boost serialization in general) well enough to adapt to my need.

Like the 2 functions below, the 1st one take an unordered_map and put in to a buffer and also return the buffer size. The 2nd one take a buffer and its size to return an unordered_map

```
void serialize(const unordered_map<int, int>& myMap, char** buf, int* bufSize);

unordered_map deserialize(char** buf, int* bufSize);
```

So how can I do that (either with or without boost)? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Question edited. Apologize for the lack of clarity before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prototypes are a bit weird with the pointer types. If we can assume to fix them into

```
void serialize(const Map& myMap, char* buf, size_t bufSize);
Map deserialize(char const* buf, size_t bufSize);
```

Here's a demo program implementing them using boost serialization:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c027a92ad1ba1b85)</kbd>**

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::unordered_map<int, std::string> Map;

void serialize(const Map& myMap, char* buf, size_t bufSize);
Map deserialize(char const* buf, size_t bufSize);

int main() {
    char buffer[4096];

    serialize({ { 1, "one" }, { 2, "two" }, /* etc */ }, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    auto data = deserialize(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

    for (auto p : data) 
        std::cout << p.first << " -> " << p.second << "\n";
}

#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/array.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>

#include <boost/serialization/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>

void serialize(const Map& myMap, char* buf, size_t bufSize)
{
    boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::array_sink> os(buf, bufSize);
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(os);

    oa << myMap;
}

Map deserialize(char const* buf, size_t bufSize)
{
    boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::array_source> is(buf, bufSize);
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(is);

    Map data;
    ia >> data;
    return data;
}
```

Prints

```
1 -> one
2 -> two
```

Comment: Thanks, works wonderfully. Two questions though: (1) I heard people mention that for serialization to buffer, we have to be careful about bit order (big endian vs little endian), does Boost solve this problem under the hood? and (2) any recommended book for Boost other than the Boost C++ Library book?

Comment: I don't know which book you refer to. You have to think about endianness whenever your data needs to be portable. Nothing to do with buffering. You can search (my) answers fir more information on portability and Boost Serialization

Answer (score -2):

Use `begin()` and `end()` of the `unordered_map` to iterate over it (and convert it to whatever you want). [Example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/begin/#example)